# Second question in an old question

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47885/limitations-on-the-conjurers-minor-conjuration-ability) contains a second question that should be removed

> And as a related issue...conjured items radiate a 5' radius dim light. Is this light visible in, say, bright daylight?

People also seems to ignore or just don't realize it exists. What is the proper etiquette in this situation? Comment and hope the owner remove it themselves? Edit/suggest edit to remove the question? Or simply close it for being too broad?

Answer (score 10):

Any of those you have rep to do.  The end goal is to remove it.   I have done so.

Comment: You can also ask the second question yourself if you want, and link to it in a comment on the OP's post, but you've no obligation to and it's only really helpful for newer users.